# Why am I getting this Syntax error?

Tags: process-builder

I'm just trying to use an IF formula in process builder and keep getting a syntax error that there is a missing ')'.

```
IF( [CampaignMember].LeadOrContactOwnerId = 00G50000003XW9e, 0052J000008G1GWQA0, [CampaignMember].LeadOrContactOwnerId )
```

Comment: The missing single quotes could be causing the problem. It should be `IF( CampaignMember.LeadOrContactOwnerId = '00G50000003XW9e', '0052J000008G1GWQA0', CampaignMember.LeadOrContactOwnerId )` or `IF( [CampaignMember].LeadOrContactOwnerId = '00G50000003XW9e', '0052J000008G1GWQA0', [CampaignMember].LeadOrContactOwnerId )`

Comment: You should really avoid using hardcoded values for the record owner ID as that assume those users will always remain the owner of those.

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues with your formula

1. Using hardcoded ID means you cannot deploy this from a Sandbox to a production org after testing without changing the owner Id string
2. Missing single quotes round the string values '00G50000003XW9e'
3. `IF ([CampaignMember].LeadOrContactOwnerId =  '00G50000003XW9e', '0052J000008G1GWQA0', [CampaignMember].LeadOrContactOwnerId )` will not return a boolean value it will return a string so will fail. A better way of doing this would be not using a formula but instead using 'Conditions are met' like the below image and using the Immediate action to change the owner id.
   [image]

You could also select a user directly using the third approach which is clearer to anyone maintaining this.

[image]